# Filter with hour and minutes

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to filter the moment of a day only with hour and minutes.

For example, a function that return true if now is between the 9.15 and 11.20 of the day.

I tried with datetime but with the minutes is littlebit complicated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime

n = datetime.datetime.now()
sta = datetime.time(19,18)
sto = datetime.time(20,19)

if sta.hour <= n.hour and n.hour <= sto.hour:
       if sta.minute <= n.minute and sto.minute <= n.minute:
               print str(n.hour) + ":" + str(n.minute)
```

What is the best way?

Regards

Comment: Please post the code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: @TomDalton the code posted can help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tuple comparisons to do any subinterval comparisons pretty easily:

```
>>> def f(dt):
...     return (9, 15) <= (dt.hour, dt.minute) < (11, 21)
...
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> str(d)
'2016-03-25 09:50:51.782718'
>>> f(d)
True
>>> f(d + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
False
```

This accepts any datetime that has time between 9:15:00.000000 and 11:20:59.999999.

---

The above method also works if you need to check for example 5 first minutes of each hour; but for the hours of day, it might be simpler to use `.time()` to get the time part of a datetime, then compare this to the limits. The following accepts any time between 9:15:00.000000 and 11:20:00.000000 (inclusive):

```
>>> def f(dt):
...     return datetime.time(9, 15) <= dt.time() <= datetime.time(11, 20)
```

Comment: I prefer the first one, because with comparisons can ignore the seconds elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the combine class method:

```
import datetime

def between():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    start = datetime.datetime.combine(now.date(), datetime.time(9, 15))
    end = datetime.datetime.combine(now.date(), datetime.time(11, 20))
    return start <= now < end
```